# Shopping Cart Price Rules: How to stop all other coupon codes from being applied to a rule that has no coupon code

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, cart-rule

Basically I have a coupon called 2Love which we used for V-day. It has stop further rule processing set to "yes", but there's no actual coupon code for it. It applies directly to the cart if there is a combination of sku's.

[image]

Now in the second picture i have a rule with a specific coupon code. It is also set to stop further rule processing. The problem is you can still enter the "welcomeback25" code if the 2LOVE is already being applied.

[image]

Perhaps it's because it's only on the right and not on the left under apply coupon.. it doesn't recognize it?

[image]

A rule that actually has a coupon code will show on both sides like the last image.

[image]

Any ideas how i can stop all other rules/coupon codes from being applied to a rule that doesn't have a coupon code.. rather just a name/label?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm reasonably sure this is going to be down to priority. Assuming the rule with the coupon doesn't also have 'stop further processing' if it was processed first then having both allowed would be my expected behaviour. Try giving the one with the coupon a priority of 10 (I think lowest number is highest priority). This way the 2Love should be processed first and prevent the other rule running.

Comment: Not sure what to say, I just tried it on a local 1.9.1.0 and got my expected behaviour. Whichever has the lowest value for priority applied to the oder. If it's the none coupon value, trying to apply the coupon reports the coupon as not valid.